# Status function. How can I give a parameter by a variable?

Tags: c++, linux

Hi!

I'm writting a program, which starts another program by status function.
My second program has an option -m, which takes a integer as value.
I want to give him a value by a variable, and I dont know how to do it.

What I mean:

```
int status = system("./ex1 -m 123");
```

And I want in place "123" put smth like that:

```
int a = 20;
int status = system("./zad1 -m a");
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream` (in `<sstream>` ) to achieve this.

Code:

```
int a = 20;
std::stringstream ss;
ss << "./zad1 -m " << a;
int status = system(ss.str().c_str());
```

Comment: Thank you, it works ;) If someone will see that, please remember to include sstream library ;)